# Is it possible to change Youtube Player parameters dynamically?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am fiddling with Youtube API for my project, with the [iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) in particular. And what I want to do is to show the player controls only when it is playing, not when it is stopeed or paused. I've searched through all the API for this feature, but it seems it is possible to change the player's appearance only by destroying at and creating a new one.

So, the question is, is it true? Or can I still change the player somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure that you can only do this by "destroying" it and starting again. As you said there is [no mention of it in the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) and the Parameters are sent on load, so you would have to resend them somehow, and not allow the reply back to change the video.

The only thing I suggest, is could you using the API trace what time in the video the change occurs, then reload the page with the new params and start the video where you left off?

Comment: I think this solution wouldn't work for me. Thanks for answer, wanted to be sure I am not missing anything here.